# Unpivoting multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, unpivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 called `anotes` with the following data

[image]

and I want to add this data into another table named final as

```
ID      Notes      NoteDate
```

With `text1, text2, text3, text4` going into the `Notes` column in the final table and `Notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4` going into `Notedate` column.

I tried unpivoting the data with notes first as:

```
select createdid, temp
from (select createdid,text1,text2,text3,text4 from anotes) p
unpivot
(temp for note in(text1,text2,text3,text4)) as unpvt
order by createdid
```

Which gave me proper results:

[image]

and then for the dates part I used another unpivot query:

```
select createdid,temp2
from (select createdid,notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4 from anotes) p
unpivot (temp2 for notedate in(notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4)) as unpvt2
```

which also gives me proper results:

[image]

Now I want to add this data into my final table.

and I tried the following query and it results into a cross join :(

```
select a.createdid, a.temp, b.temp2
from (select createdid, temp
      from (select createdid,text1,text2,text3,text4 from anotes) p
      unpivot
      (temp for note in(text1,text2,text3,text4)) as unpvt) a inner join (select createdid,temp2
from (select createdid,notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4 from anotes) p
unpivot (temp2 for notedate in(notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4)) as unpvt) b on a.createdid=b.createdid
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Is there any way where I can unpivot both the columns at the same time?

Or use two select queries to add that data into my final table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [this blog](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html) or just search for SQL Multiple Unpivot

Comment: Thanks for the link @AHiggins, Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I would say the most concise, and probably most efficient way to unpivot multiple columns is to use [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) along with a [table valued constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT  t.CreatedID, upvt.Text, upvt.NoteDate
FROM    anotes t
        CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES
            (Text1, NoteDate1),
            (Text2, NoteDate2),
            (Text3, NoteDate3),
            (Text4, NoteDate4),
            (Text5, NoteDate5),
            (Text6, NoteDate6),
            (Text7, NoteDate7)
        ) upvt (Text, NoteDate);
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3aeb9/2)**

---

**ADDENDUM**

I find the concept quite a hard one to explain, but I'll try. A table valued constuctor is simply a way of defining a table on the fly, so

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2)) t (a, b);
```

Will Create a table with Alias t with data:

```
a   b
------
1   1
2   2
```

So when you use it inside the APPLY you have access to all the outer columns, so it is just a matter of defining your constructed tables with the correct pairs of values (i.e. text1 with date1).

Comment: Whoa, I think you win.  That does perform best.  Now I just have to try and figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Used the link above mentioned by @AHiggins

Following is my final query!

```
select createdid,temp,temp2
from (select createdid,text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4,notedate5,notedate6,notedate7 from anotes) main
      unpivot
      (temp for notes in(text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7)) notes
unpivot (temp2 for notedate in(notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4,notedate5,notedate6,notedate7)) Dates
where RIGHT(notes,1)=RIGHT(notedate,1)
```

Comment: Great!  Mark this question as answered (look for the checkbox next to your own answer) so that the system recognizes the issue has been addressed, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Treat each query as a table and join them together based on the createdid and the fieldid (the numeric part of the field name).

```
select x.createdid, x.textValue, y.dateValue
from
(
    select createdid, substring(note, 5, len(note)) fieldId, textValue
    from (select createdid,text1,text2,text3,text4 from anotes) p
    unpivot
    (textValue for note in(text1,text2,text3,text4)) as unpvt
)x
join
(
    select createdid, substring(notedate, 9, len(notedate)) fieldId, dateValue
    from (select createdid,notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4 from anotes) p
    unpivot (dateValue for notedate in(notedate1,notedate2,notedate3,notedate4)) as unpvt2
) y on x.fieldId = y.fieldId and x.createdid = y.createdid
order by x.createdid, x.fieldId
```

The other answer given won't work if you have too many columns and the rightmost number of the field name is duplicated (e.g. text1 and text11).