# Unpivoting multiple columns displaying incorrect data and duplicates

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have a books table which has subject and chapterwise total pages and entered pages. Below is the screenshot of my table.

[image: tbl_books]

I am unpivoting this table based on the total pages and entered pages based on subject something like the one below

[image: tbl_books_upv]

Below is my query that I am using for unpivot

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT UID
       ,[Subject]
       ,TotalPages
       ,PagesEntered
    FROM ( SELECT UID
               ,[Subject]
               ,[Chapter1PagesEntered]
               ,[Chapter2PagesEentered]
               ,[Chapter1TotalPages]
               ,[Chapter2TotalPages]
            FROM [dbo].[tbl_books]
         ) AS SRC UNPIVOT ( TotalPages FOR Cities IN ( [Chapter1TotalPages],
                                                      [Chapter2TotalPages] ) ) AS upv UNPIVOT ( PagesEntered FOR Suppliers IN ( [Chapter1PagesEntered],
                                                              [Chapter2PagesEentered] ) ) AS upv
    WHERE RIGHT(TotalPages, 1) = RIGHT(PagesEntered, 1);
```

If you see the second screenshot the rows highlighted in orange box, the unpivot is giving me duplicate values something like cross product and also in the last the output values are not matching the original values. The first few rows are 
returning correct values however in the last and in middle its not.

For example for subject 101004, the total pages must be **24  24** for first row and **14  14** for the second row. Howver the query returns as **24  24** in first row, **24  14** in second row, **14  14** in third and **14  24** in fourth row.

Likewise Subject 103009 needs to return **15  12** in first row and **14  4** in the second. however i'm getting only one row with **14  4**

I tried changing the WHERE RIGHT(TotalPages, 1) = RIGHT(PagesEntered, 1); however i'm not getting my desired output. I am not able to find what is causing this incorrect values.

I tried the codes provided in the below link however they are not solving my problem.

[Unpivoting Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064999/unpivoting-multiple-columns)

[Unpivoting Multiple Columns](http://pratchev.blogspot.in/2009/02/unpivoting-multiple-columns.html)

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f01d/1) link. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the APPLY-Operator instead of UNPIVOT.

For example:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT r.* FROM (VALUES (1,'101001',16,14,16,14), 
                        (2,'101002',16,14,16,14),
                        (3,'101003',16,14,16,14),
                        (2,'101004',24,14,24,14)) AS r(UID,Subject,Chapter1PagesEntered,Chapter2PagesEntered,Chapter1TotalPages,Chapter2TotalPages)
)
SELECT CTE.UID, A.Chapter, A.Subject, A.PagesEntered, A.TotalPages
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Chapter1',UID,Subject,Chapter1PagesEntered, Chapter1TotalPages),
                   ('Chapter2',UID,Subject,Chapter2PagesEntered, Chapter2TotalPages)) AS A(Chapter,UID, Subject,PagesEntered,TotalPages);
```

I need the CTE because I have no table like yours.

Comment: Hi, Thanks... Your query solved my problem. How will the performance for the query... I will have more than lakhs of records...

Comment: To my experience. APPLY instead of UNPIVOT performs better in such a case. But you should test it as always in your environment